# Nv-d3-directive TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined angular

Tags: angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am getting and error while to try to integrate the data which i get from the api.

I have included the following files in the index.html:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.9/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/lib/angularjs-nvd3-directives/dist/angularjs-nvd3-directives.js"></script>
```

This is my html code :

```
<div class="col-md-4 overflow-graph">
   <nvd3-line-chart
     data="exampleData"
     id="exampleId"
     xAxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormatFunction()"
     yAxisTickFormat="yAxisTickFormatFunction()"
     width="550"
     height="350"
     showXAxis="true"
     showYAxis="true">
     <svg></svg>
   </nvd3-line-chart>
</div>
```

This is where i am getting the data from

```
$scope.exampleData = function(){
   for(var count in $scope.skuproduceCart) {
     var forecast = $scope.skuproduceCart[count].forecast;
   }
   return forecast;
};
```

forecast return an array of objects with a a structure

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

This is the error i get :

```
nv.d3.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js:5:56
    at Array.filter (native)
    at SVGSVGElement.<anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js:5:22)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.9/d3.min.js:5:3691
    at C (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.9/d3.min.js:1:3397)
    at Array.Cs.each (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.9/d3.min.js:5:3643)
    at Array.b (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js:4:31618)
    at Array.ma.call (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.9/d3.min.js:3:9080)
    at checkElementID (http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/lib/angularjs-nvd3-directives/dist/angularjs-nvd3-directives.js:795:216)
    at Scope.$scope.d3Call (http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/lib/angularjs-nvd3-directives/dist/angularjs-nvd3-directives.js:884:15)
```

Please let me know if additional info is required will gladly provide it.

Any help or guidance appreciated.

Thanks in advance.